# Integration by partial fractions

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I've attempted to integrate the function $$\frac{2x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x + 4}{(x^2 + 2x + 2)^2}$$ using several techniques, but none of them are solving it nicely.
I've tried to slve it by partial fractions:
$$\frac{A + Bx}{x^2 + 2x + 2} + \frac{C + Dx}{(x^2 + 2x + 2)^2},$$ but i get wrong coefficients.

Comment: did you try W|A?

Comment: @Alex, I'm sorry i dont know English well. Can you explain me what is the W|A?

Comment: It's Wolfram Alpha.
http://wolframalpha.com/

Comment: wolframalpha.com. It uses pseudocode, so just partfrac(your fraction) and see what you get

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! I took the liberty to clear up your fractions and make them more readable. For future reference, please use [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your fractions, functions and much more in a nicer way.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Hello @RüstəmRövşənKərimov ! Welcome to MSE. If you need any help sir, please don't hesitate to ask me through the comments! You've asked a good question. As suggested, you should use Wolfram Alpha to get some doubts related to integrals and computation. For this case, here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%282x%5E3%2B5x%5E2%2B8x%2B4%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2x%2B2%29%5E2

Comment: Try arriving at the solution, and if problems persist, please do mention that in the comments. Then I'll try helping you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us start with $$\frac{2x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x + 4}{(x^2 + 2x + 2)^2}=\frac{A + Bx}{x^2 + 2x + 2} + \frac{C + Dx}{(x^2 + 2x + 2)^2}$$ Remove the denominator, expand and group the terms. You should arrive to $$2x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x + 4=B x^3+ (A+2 B)x^2+(2 A+2 B+D)x+(2 A+C)$$ which gives the four equations $B=2$,$A+2B=5$ so $A=1$, $2A+2B+D=8$ so $D=2$, $2A+C=4$ so $C=2$.

So we have $$\frac{2x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x + 4}{(x^2 + 2x + 2)^2}=\frac{1 + 2x}{x^2 + 2x + 2} + \frac{2 + 2x}{(x^2 + 2x + 2)^2}=\frac{2x+2-1}{x^2 + 2x + 2} + \frac{2x + 2}{(x^2 + 2x + 2)^2}$$ So, setting $u=x^2+2x+2$, you can notice that $2x+2$ is just $u'$ which make things very simple for two parts and what is basically left is $$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+2x+2}=\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2+1}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get the partial fraction form by separating the numerator into multiples of $x^2+2x+2$:

$$2x^3+5x^2+8x+4 = 2x(x^2+2x+2)+x^2+4x+4$$
$$=2x(x^2+2x+2)+(x^2+2x+2) + 2x+2$$
$$=(2x+1)(x^2+2x+2) + 2x+2$$

Once you cancel the $x^2+2x+2$ from the first part you are left with the partial fraction form, and from then on integrate as above.